# Xml parsing from web response

Tags: python, xml, web-services, nominatim

I'm trying to get response from nominatim to geo-code few thousands of cities.

```
import os
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

txt = open('input.txt', 'r').readlines()
for line in txt:
 lp, region, district, municipality, city = line.split('\t')
 baseUrl = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/gb/'+region+'/'+district+'/'+municipality+'/'+city+'/?format=xml' 
 # eg. http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/pl/podkarpackie/stalowowolski/Bojan%C3%B3w/Zapu%C5%9Bcie/?format=xml
 resp = requests.get(baseUrl)
 resp.encoding = 'UTF-8' # special diacritics
 msg = resp.text
 # parse response to get lat & long
 tree = ET.parse(msg)
 root = tree.getroot()
 print tree
```

but the result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "geo_miasta.py", line 17, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 647, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")    
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n<searchresults timestamp=\'Tue, 11 Feb 14 21:13:50 +0000\' attribution=\'Data \xa9 OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\' querystring=\'\u015awierczyna, Drzewica, opoczy\u0144ski, \u0142\xf3dzkie, gb\' polygon=\'false\' more_url=\'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&amp;exclude_place_ids=&amp;q=%C5%9Awierczyna%2C+Drzewica%2C+opoczy%C5%84ski%2C+%C5%82%C3%B3dzkie%2C+gb\'>\n</searchresults>'
```

What is wrong with this?

Edit:
Thant to @rob my solution is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

txt = open('input.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')

for line in txt:
    lp, region, district, municipality, city = line.split('\t')
    baseUrl = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/pl/'+region+'/'+district+'/'+municipality+'/'+city+'/?format=xml'
    resp = requests.get(baseUrl)
    msg = resp.content
    tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
    for place in tree.findall('place'):
    location = '{:5f}\t{:5f}'.format(
        float(place.get('lat')),
        float(place.get('lon')))

    f = open('result.txt', 'a')
    f.write(location+'\t'+region+'\t'+district+'\t'+municipality+'\t'+city)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using [`xml.etree.ElementTree.parse()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse), which takes a filename or a file object as an argument. But, you are not passing a file or file object in, you are passing a unicode string.

Try [`xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(text)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring).

Like this:

```
 tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
```

Here is a complete sample program:

```
import os
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

baseUrl = 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search/pl/podkarpackie/stalowowolski/Bojan%C3%B3w/Zapu%C5%9Bcie\n/?format=xml'
resp = requests.get(baseUrl)
msg = resp.content
tree = ET.fromstring(msg)
for place in tree.findall('place'):
  print u'{:s}: {:+.2f}, {:+.2f}'.format(
    place.get('display_name'),
    float(place.get('lon')),
    float(place.get('lat'))).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks, this move the error border to encoding space: ` UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 115: ordinal not in range(128) `

Comment: @m93 - That is because you are using `resp.text` instead of `resp.content`. See my edit for a complete program that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os,sys,time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
tree = ET.parse('D:\Reddy\BankLoanAcctService_transactionInq.xml')
root=tree.getroot()

for TrxnEffDt in root.iter('TrxnEffDt'):
 new_TrxnEffDt= str(time.strftime("%y-%m-%d"))
 TrxnEffDt=str(new_TrxnEffDt)

filename2 ="D:\Reddy\BankLoanAcctService_transactionInq2.txt"
r=open(filename2,'w')
sys.stdout =r
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Reddy\Python\new.py", line 4, in <module>
    tree = ET.parse('D:\Reddy\BankLoanAcctService_transactionInq.xml')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1242, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1730, in parse
    self._root = parser._parse(source)
  File "<string>", line None
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0

Comment: This is the error message i am getting. pls help me

Comment: You should probably ask your own question instead of using an answer on this topic (to avoid confusion and be sure to get a solution to your specific problem), and, if you think the problem is related, you should put a link to this one to help answerers.