# xml.etree.ElementTree for chinese

Tags: python, xml

Given an XML with chinese characters, I would like to use `xml.etree` to help me parse the XML to do some processing. The English version works. For example:

```sh
>el.xml printf '%s\n' $'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?><Color>Grey</Color>'
>cl.xml printf '%s\n' $'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?><Color>灰色</Color>'

tryParse() {
  python -c 'import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET; import sys; ET.parse(sys.argv[1])' "$@"
}

tryParse el.xml && printf '%s\n\n' "English works"
tryParse cl.xml && printf '%s\n\n' "Chinese works"
```

...emits as output:

```
English works

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1182, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 656, in parse
    parser.feed(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
    self._raiseerror(v)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
    raise err
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 44
```

Comment: You need `ET.fromstring()`, not `ET.parse()`; this code is looking for a **file** with `<Color>` in its name.

Comment: ...which is to say -- the code given here, *if* we fix the broken variable names, is then a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21713527/xml-parsing-from-web-response or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064247/cant-parse-xml-effectively-using-python, which share the same underlying cause.

Comment: one second let me change the code.

Comment: ...with Python 2.7.10, I **don't** get a ParseError after copying-and-pasting this code as-edited into a brand new interpreter window.

Comment: Also see http://ideone.com/pZBo5b, where your code runs without throwing any exceptions in an online interpreter.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I have made the necessary changes to the code.

Comment: i use python 2.7 so thanks for using that.

Comment: okay, **that's** reproducing now.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the Header e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` from your `XML`File?

Comment: I've edited in a proper [mcve] -- code that someone else can copy-and-paste to see the problem that contains nothing extraneous to same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) instead:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>> doc = ET.parse('cl.xml')
>>> print doc.getroot().text
灰色
```

Comment: hi, when i check the contents in the node, is it also chinese characters?